# How can I pagination when I use solr facet stats?

Tags: java, solr

I have select all records from solr by solr facet stats, but I can't pagination them, How can I pagination by the pageSize and pageNum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pagination when use solr facet stats, because use solr facet stats will stats all document.